# Root-relative URL not working in CSS

Tags: html, css, url

I have the below CSS

```
.div_img {

     width: 500px;
     height: 500px;
     background-image: url(/images/simple_img.png);
   }
```

There is root relative URL in above CSS , but its not working. It is not showing an image on that div. Please help me to how to set root relative URL in CSS?

Comment: Are you implying that the absolute version of that URL works?

Comment: Check through `Developer tools` on Chrome and other related tools on other browser

Comment: What @bjan said, Firebug for firefox, Develper tools for chrome etc have a network tab, which is useful to see if resources are downloaded, e.g. paths are correct. Also using these tools to inspect your `div` will let you know if any other CSS clases or rules are over-riding `.div_img`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that:

1. The image exists in that location
2. The css file is rendered
3. The `div` has is `class` attribute set to `div_img`
4. The `background-image` property is not getting overridden by another css directive that takes precedence

Answer (score -3):

Check if you have permission for that image. If you are a Linux user, type -R 777 /path/to/project/file

Comment: 777 is completely unnecessary -- this would enable write access to all users on the local machine. 664 would be fine (owner/group R/W, others R)